# What is the best / correct way to export Docker image with reduced size

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile

My task is to create simple Java application with Spring Boot + mongo embedded mode ,then save and deploy it on Docker. So someone else will take this snapshot and run in his local environment. But I'm a little confuse what exactly to export either the container or image , etc...

My steps:
1. Create Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/docker-spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar docker-spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

2.

```
Create image

    docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-test .
```

3.

```
    vitalys-MBP:docker-spring-boot$ docker images
    REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
    docker-test         latest              644e2f818027        15 minutes ago      762MB
    openjdk             8                   7c57090325cc        2 weeks ago         737MB


//save on the image
docker save docker-test > docker_test_image.tar

//export on the container
docker export docker_container > docker_container.tar
```

My Question is:

I see each of the .tar files them almost 760MB I cannot really able to send 1.5GB , Maybe I don't need to export the container or I missing something here ?? (what are the correct steps in order to import the app on other docker running with java)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is correct only. As the base image `openjdk:8` is already 737MB, your application is 25 MB only. You can push your built image to docker-hub, and ask respective users to pull from there. As you try to save images, I assume that your user might not have access to pull from docker-hub.

In order to minimize the size of docker image, you can use jre image instead (e.g. [openjdk:8-jre-sim](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) has the size about 205 MB only). You can further reduce jre image by building your own, one of tutorial can be found [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/minimal-java-docker-containers/). However, not much improvement is gained, so I would recommend you to use the official jre image.

Comment: Thanks, do i need make save , and export on these 2 "tar" files (for image and for container ) , Or just make save to images will enough ? what I need to supply to other person (Docker) that my app will run there...?

Comment: only one is enough. The base image is already embedded in result built image already.

Comment: Base image is the "docker save docker-test > docker_test_image.tar" ? or "docker export docker_container > docker_container.tar" ?

Comment: Base image is the one you mentioned in `FROM ...` statement in Dockerfile. In your example, its openjdk:8. In short, you need to share your docker-test image only.

Comment: Thanks , last question before I did the image save , Am I need to run the "Docker" or it doesn't effect the result  of save?

Comment: `docker run` is not required, just make sure your recent built image is showing in `docker images` with correct timestamp.